# How to pass http credentials to Elasticsearch from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-5

I have `Elasticsearch` and `Kibana` `5.2.1` installed on my `Linux RHEL 7.2` machine. When I hit my Kibana URL in chrome browser `http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:5601` it will navigate to my customized authentication page. Once the credentials are authenticated then it will navigate it to `Kibana Discover` page. I would like to pass those credentials to elasticsearch like in this format. `http://<<username>>:<<pwd>>localhost:9200/<<index-name>>`.

Is there any plugins or confguration is available to achieve this?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do... Kibana behind the scene does authenticate to Elasticsearch, otherwise it wouldn't be able to see the data in Discover page and other dashboards. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndreiStefan. I have installed read only rest api plugin in elasticsearch. I made some of the indices as read only as per the user and group. The same thing I am trying to achieve it in Kibana also. When I hit my URL page it will ask for an authentication by that time the kibana should pass the credentials to the elasticsearch and made that indices authoriation so that only corresponding users can view their respective dashboards only.